# Need help / advise in sub directory creation in php

Tags: php, subdirectory, plesk

Let's consider a showroom with multiple branches. Assume the parent showroom name is "abc". Suppose it has 3 franchises. efg ,jkl ,xyz. All these franchises sharing the same products as in the parent "abc".

Here I have the parent domain name **[www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)**. It has 3 subdomains **abc.com/efg , abc.com/jkl, abc.com/xyz**

The MySQL DB tables in abc.com are **products, franchises**.
The table products consist of showroom products and the franchise consists of their corresponding logos and address. Here the data from the products table is shared in multiple subdirectories. The data insertion to the franchise table is done by the admin of parent "abc".

My goal is to create different URLs for different franchises.ie **abc.com/efg , abc.com/jkl, abc.com/xyz** .

I **dont need to create** subdirectories in the server. Is there any solution for this??

My server is VPS with Plesk control panel

Comment: Those aren't subdomains, looking at the URLs. They look like folders / routes instead

Comment: Anyway if all the franchises actually have the same products, then it's not really clear what the difficulty is or why you would need these extra routes. Or can they add more products specific to the franchise. You haven't explained the situation very clearly and also it's also a bit unclear what the actual issue is. If you're not creating subdirectories then presumably you're using a PHP framework which has a routing framework to generate arbitrary URLs to specific resources. We can't really answer your question because we don't know the platform or the full situation

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is URL Rewriting, that would allow you to have a folder in your url but it can be resolved as a variable in your code that you can use to load different logos in your site depending on the url sharing the same codebase without copying code to subfolders.